# Convert from Datetime.ToFileTime() to DateTime object

Tags: c#

How to convert from `DateTime.ToFileTime()` back to a `DateTime` object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess DateTime.FromFileTime()

Answer (score 5):

```
    long value = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime();
    DateTime when = DateTime.FromFileTime(value);
```